# Call parent class' initialize function?

Tags: ruby

I have little experience with Ruby, and I come from C++, where initializer lists are commonly used. One thing about Ruby that I would like to know is the following:

Given the following class Vehicle and its subclass Car:

```
class Vehicle
 attr_reader :wheels
 def initialize(wheels)
  @wheels = wheels 
 end
end 

class Car < Vehicle
 def initialize(car_stuff)
  @wheels = 4 # this is the part I don't like! ;)
  @car_stuff = car_stuff
 end 
end
```

**Is there a way of calling the superclass constructor method** instead of going through the different variables that class `Vehicle` may have?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's what `super` is for:

```
class Car < Vehicle
  def initialize(car_stuff)
    super(4)
    @car_stuff = car_stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm such a noob.. :_)

Comment: There is no such thing as a constructor in Ruby. It's all just methods. Ruby only has one kind of subroutines: instance methods. No class methods, no static methods, no constructors, no non-virtual functions, no free functions. Once you realize that, it should be obvious why `super` works the same way here as it does in every other method.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you, but "No class methods, no static methods .."?  I can define Car#foo or Car.foo and whether they are different things or I am missing something! :D

Comment: The latter is singleton method of `Car` object (remember classes in Ruby are objects).

Comment: Yes, and singleton methods are actually just regular instance methods of the singleton class. There are only instance methods. Period. Experienced Rubyists will sometimes talk about "singleton methods" or "class methods", but they will know that those are actually "instance methods of the singleton class" and "instance methods of the class object's singleton class" … it's just a mouthful to say that properly, so we abbreviate sometimes. Unfortunately, that is confusing to newbies.